# -bash: geth: command not found in OS X EI Capitan

Tags: go-ethereum

I am new in Ethereum. I set up all the things as per guidelines but when I try `geth help` command it gives an error :

> -bash: geth: command not found in OS X EI Capitan

**Edit:**
[the link which I follow](http://the%20link%20which%20I%20follow)

Help me to install geth.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help someone answer this question if you indicated which instructions you were following.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a Mac, the easiest way to do it is via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), install that first then its just these 2 commands.

```
brew tap ethereum/ethereum
brew install ethereum
```

See https://www.ethereum.org/cli for more info.

Comment: ok let me try this link

Comment: I remove Homebrew and again install and it works.